# Get font file from Windows using in Excel file

Tags: excel, fonts

I don't known this question is exactly or not in this box

But I have an excel file using font with name "IPA P明朝" (display in Excel)

So can I get real font file from C:\Windows\Fonts. (ttf or ttc file)

Because I tried to search but have no font with the name "IPA P明朝"

I think the font name display in Excel is not indeticaly with real file name

Comment: The name of the font is `IPA PMincho`. I have no idea how you should go about getting the name though.

Comment: Yes, I can get ENGLISH name  from Google translate :D, but have no luck

Comment: It's out of the box - google can quite easily tell you that IPA Mincho is a free font and give you the download location for it. (specifically: https://ipafont.ipa.go.jp/old/ipafont/download.html#en)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that, I need to get the BOLD version of IPA PMincho. In windows can be display Bold but in ipafont.ipa.go.jp only have normal version. That why I need to get from Windows